# android: import xml file from sd card to sqlite database

Tags: android, sql, xml

I have xml file stored in my SD card and i want to read this xml and import data to SQLite database which already exist and have more then one table.

this is my xml code http://pastebin.com/ZpBenFDe which is saved on sd card and i want to read it 
I want this xml data put to my database

this is my code to create database and i want fill this tables http://pastebin.com/nG6Aaaiu

Comment: question is really large. What have you implemented for now ? read file ? parse of xml content ? ContentProvider for database operations ?